# Finding the spectral density of a fraction of two noisy variables

Tags: spectral-analysis, noise

I have a certain expression $\Phi=C \frac{V}{R}$ where $C$ is a constant, and both $V$ and $R$ are noisy variables; they are set to some working point value, but they have some small noise component (lets call their amplitudes $\delta V(t)$ and $\delta R(t)$) that varies over time that is specified by their noise spectral densities $S_{VV}(f)$ and $S_{RR}(f)$, which I know. I'm now looking for a way to calculate the resulting noise spectral density $S_{\Phi\Phi}(f)$, and I'm not sure how this works.

My first thought was doing a two variable Taylor expansion, but I'm not sure how much sense that makes. You'd get something like $\Phi/C \approx \frac{V}{R} + \frac{\delta V(t)}{R} - \frac{V\delta R(t)}{R^2} - \frac{\delta V(t)\delta R(t)}{R^2} + \frac{V(\delta R (t))^2}{R^3}$ . Not entirely sure if that makes sense, and how to continue from there.

In principle $R$ and $V$ are independent variables, that might help.